# How do I restrict a specific scope just to users with a specific role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, rolify, cancancan

So I have a `Post` model. My `posts` can be either published or unpublished. I am using Rolify, CanCanCan and Devise.

What I want to happen is my `:admin` users, should be able to view the `Post#Show` action of all Posts, but my `:member` or `guest` users (i.e. non-logged in) should only ever be able to see `Post.published` posts.

My `ability.rb` looks like this:

```
   if user.has_role? :admin
        can :manage, :all
    #Member
    elsif user.has_role? :member
        can :read, :all
        can :create, Post
        can :status, Post
        can :update, Post do |post|
            post.try(:user) == user
        end
    #Guest
    else
        can :read, :all
        can :create, Post
        can :status, Post
    end
```

I tried doing this, for both `:member` and `Guest`, but it gave me an endless redirect loop on my `Post#Index` page - which is my `root_path`:

```
    can :read, Post.published
```

Where `Post.published` returns an array of all the posts with `publication_status = "published"`.

This is how I declared that on my `Post.rb`:

```
enum publication_status: [ :unpublished, :published ]
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

In my `Post#Show`, I simply did this:

```
  def show
    if current_user and current_user.has_role? :admin or :editor
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    else
      @post = Post.published.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

That works like a charm.

If someone has a more elegant way, say inside the `ability.rb` I would love to know.

I tried many permutations using blocks and all this jazz in the `ability.rb` but nothing worked.

I also had to remove the default added `set_post` method in my controller, because `cancancan` already `loads_and_authorize` the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#Member
elsif user.has_role? :member
    can :read,   Post, publication_status: :published
    can :create, Post
    can :status, Post
    can :update, Post, user_id: user.id
 # same goes for the Guest user
```

this will work given that you have a column named `publication_status` in the `Post` model